# How can I disable Office 2007 online help function using GPOs?

Tags: group-policy, microsoft-office

As the title says: How can I disable the online help function in Office 2007 using a group policy? I just can't find a relevant setting within the administrative templates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's the `Online Content` setting, located at:

`User Configuration` -> `Administrative Templates` -> `Classic Administrative Templates` -> `Microsoft Office 2007 system` -> `Tools` -> `Options` -> `General` -> `Service Options...` -> `Online Content`

The National Institute of Standards and Technology (NIST), through the National Vulnerabilities Database (NVD) has lots of good Excel spreadsheets on the various GPO options Microsoft provides for Active Directory, so they're a good resource for this kind of thing in generall.  Their [spreadsheet on Office 2k7 is here](https://nvd.nist.gov/static/feeds/cce/cce-office2k7-5.20130214.xls), and this setting is in row 8, "CCE-967-0."